# parse a string from tag django

Tags: django, parsing, django-templates

I have a custom template tag

```
{% perpage 10 20 30 40 50 %}
```

User can write his own numbers instead of this 10,20 etc. Also, the amount of these numbers is defined by user. How can I parse this tag and read this numbers?
I want to use "for"-instruction

UPDATE:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('pagination/perpageselect.html')
def perpageselect (parser, token):
    """
    Splits the arguments to the perpageselect tag and formats them correctly.
    """
    split = token.split_contents()
    choices = None
    x = 1
    for x in split:
        choices = int(split[x])
    return {'choices': choices}
```

so, i have this function. i need to get arguments (numbers) from template tag, and convert them to integers. Then, i need to make a submit form for passing the choice like a GET parameter to URL `(...&perpage=10)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Django 1.4, you can define a [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) that takes positional or keyword arguments. You can loop through these in the template.

```
@register.simple_tag
def perpage(*args):
    for x in args:
        number = int(x)
        # do something with x
    ...
    return "output string"
```

When you use the `perpage` tag in your templates,

```
{% perpage 10 20 30 %}
```

the `perpage` template tag function will be called with the positional arguments `"10", "20", "30"`. It would be equivalent to calling the following in the view:

```
 per_page("10", "20", "30")
```

In the example `perpage` function I wrote above, `args` is the `("10", "20", "30")`. You can loop through `args`, convert the strings to integers, and do whatever you wish with the numbers. Finally, your function should return the output string you wish to display in the template.

### Update

For an inclusion tag, you don't need to parse the token. The inclusion tag does that for you, and provide them as positional arguments. In the example below, I've converted the numbers to integers, you can change it as necessary. I've defined a `PerPageForm` and overridden the `__init__` method to set the choices.

```
from django import forms
class PerPageForm(forms.Form):
    perpage = forms.ChoiceField(choices=())

    def __init__(self, choices, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PerPageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['perpage'].choices = [(str(x), str(x)) for x in choices]

@register.inclusion_tag('pagination/perpageselect.html')
def perpage (*args):
    """
    Splits the arguments to the perpageselect tag and formats them correctly.
    """
    choices = [int(x) for x in args]
    perpage_form = PerPageForm(choices=choices)
    return {'perpage_form': perpage_form}
```

Then in your template, display the form field with `{{ perpage_form.perpage }}`

Comment: but it will define "perpage" like split[0], or not? i need to parse only numbers. is it means that i need to start from x=1?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I've updated my answer, hopefully that explains better.

Comment: I used it, but it's don't working. How can i use it with `split = token.split_contents()` and inclusion_tag?

Comment: Inclusion tags and simple tags are shortcuts. When you use them, you don't have to use `token.split_contents()` because it's taken care of for you. Try implementing the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) then modify them to get the result you need. If you can't get it to work, update your answer with what you've tried and it will be easier to help you. If you can get the tag working for a fixed number of arguments (e.g. 2 or 3), then it will be fairly straight forward to accept any number of arguments.

Comment: See my updated answer, you don't have to use `token.split_contents()`.

Comment: and some little question: how can i make a select form with all of these choices and pass the selected choice as parameter in URL?
(...&perpage=10)

Comment: You can create a form in the inclusion tag, then render it in your `pagination/perpageselect.html` template.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/ this document saing, that i need to use class for making form. How can i make the form without class?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I've given you an example of how you can define a form class, and use the form in your template. If you don't want to use that approach, you can build the `<select>` tag manually in the template, but that's harder work.

Comment: Excuse me, sir, but can you tell me how to make it manually in the template? Your previous advice is working perfect, but i want to know how to do it manually, without form class

Comment: You would put the [`<select>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) tag manually in the template, then use a for loop to go through the choices, creating an `<option>` tag for each one. Finally, close the `</select>` tag.

Comment: and how i will get the "...?perpage=20" in the URL? i already used your advice, but i dont know what must be in form action(((

Comment: The form action should be the url that you want the form data submitted to,  probably `"" ` or `"." `. Note you need to include the `<form>` tag in your template, even when you generate the `perpage` field using the form class.

Comment: It's tricky to help you in the comments without seeing all your code. Because you've marked this question as answered not many people will see it. You might have a better response if you start a new question. Hope you get it working.